# Oracle database embedded JVM

Tags: oracle, jvm, java

How can we identify which JRE version is supported by Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 64 bit (embedded JVM)

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer for determining which jvm version is used on Oracle database

Here is the solution:

If You need to find out which java/jdk version in installed along Your Oracle server You can create function and than retrieve java version direcly from JDK. First create function...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_java_property (prop IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS LANGUAGE JAVA
name 'java.lang.System.getProperty(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
```

.. and then get the version

```
SELECT get_java_property('java.version') FROM dual;
```

If You cannot create such function, general rule is that in default installation: Oracle 9 uses JDK 1.3, Oracle 10 uses JDK 1.4.

Comment: and Oracle 11 uses JDK 1.6

Comment: Certified versions are:

The Oracle 11g database embedded JVM supports JRE 1.5.
The Oracle 10g database embedded JVM supports JRE 1.4.
The Oracle 9i database embedded JVM supports JRE 1.3.

Comment: @user2079954 I've been looking all over for a list like that. Thanks alot. Do you know of a place on the internet which lists all DBMS versions vs Java versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid having to write the function if you run this query:

```
SELECT  dbms_java.get_ojvm_property(PROPSTRING=>'java.version') FROM dual
```

Which will output something like this:

```
SQL> /

DBMS_JAVA.GET_OJVM_PROPERTY(PROPSTRING=>'JAVA.VERSION')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.5.0_10
```